# Why this activity hangs if i add connection to remote json (and then parsing)?

Tags: android, json, http, parsing, connection

i created the following activity and it loads well if i add comment to getData() method. If i remove comment then i connect to remote url to fetch and parse json data. This seems to make slower the load of the activity.
It loads instantly if i add comment to GetData() call; it loads in 4-5 seconds if it use GetData(). Here is my activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    Spinner method;
    EditText amount;
    EditText address;
    EditText email;
    EditText total;
    Button sendButton;
    List<String> methods;
    String selected_method;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

        method = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerBuy); // Spinner element
        amount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editImporto);
        address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editAddress);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
        total = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTotale);
        sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        method.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        methods = new ArrayList<String>();
        methods.add("Method 1");
        methods.add("Method 2");
        methods.add("Method 3");
        methods.add("Method 4");

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.my_simple_spinner_item, methods);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.my_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        method.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        try {
            getData();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void getData() throws JSONException {
        int timeout = 10;
        String jsonString = null;

        BasicHttpParams basicParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(basicParams, timeout * 1000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(basicParams, timeout * 1000 );
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(basicParams);

        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://www.example.com/data.json");
        request.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(in);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }

            jsonString = stringBuilder.toString();

        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

What could be the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: this is happening because you are doing a network operation. so it is obviously going to take longer. Is it even your code `:P`.

Comment: Do you know any way to optimize it?

Comment: @smartmouse: Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run network operation using an async class. Async classhas a method which you override called doInBackground which does not run on the UI Thread.

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        //Here write your network request

        //to obtain result instead of returning null..return the String reply
        return reply;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        //This part runs after the async is ready, and yes this is back to the UI thread

       //s is the reply from the doInBackgroud returned value
    }
}
```

Then you run the task like so

```
new MyAsyncTask().execute();
```

**UPDATE - PROGRESS BAR**

To include a progress bar you have to also override the onPreExecute method..which also runs in the ui thread and it runs before the doInBackground method..so on the preExecute you display progress bar..

first declare a global progress bar

```
ProgressDialog progress;
```

Then the Pre Execute Method

```
 @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        progress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "dialog title",
                "dialog message", true);
    }
```

and in the postExecute add

```
progress.dismiss();
```

to remove the progress bar

**UPDATE!! - Network Connection**

You can check for the network with this method..

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
            = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

**To Use**

```
if(isNetworkAvailable(context)){
   new MyAsyncTask().execute();
}else{
   //No Internet don't run task
}
```

Comment: It works, now it loads instantly. It is the first time i use AsyncTask... so now how to get value obtained in AsyncTask back to main activity?

Comment: i am updating the answer

Comment: see updated answer..in the doOnBackgroud return the reply as a string..and grab it into the postExecute method

Comment: Sorry, can you tell me how to add a progress bar? Because before the value is available i get a nullPointerException... i mean this one: http://sampleprogramz.com/images/android/ProgressBar_Styles_1.jpg

Comment: I having problem with "this" as argument of .show... maybe getApplicationContext() is better?

Comment: Getting this error: `02-23 12:59:26.956: E/AndroidRuntime(29645): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application`

Comment: no please use YourActivityName.this (if you are in a fragment use the host activity name.this)

Comment: AMAZING! Thank you for your support! You make me to figure out some things that i did not know :)

Comment: i'm so happy i can help u :D

Comment: Sorry if i contact you back but i noticed a bug: if there is not data connection or bad connection the app crashes (here is the error: http://pastebin.com/Xs8XcXYb . So how to handle if user had not connection in that while or if the server is unavailable?

Comment: I add the check before `new MyAsyncTask().execute();` Am i right?

Comment: updated answer, you only have to pass the context to isNetworkAvailable

Comment: It is exactly what i did... but i would have more to ask you about this... can we chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71590/discussion-between-johan-v-and-smartmouse).

Answer (score 1):

This is because all network operation must be done in non-UI thread. You can use async classes for Network operation like this:

```
 private class GetDataAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void > {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        //Get Data
      getData();

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(void result) {
 //anything you want to do it on UI 
    }
}
```

Comment: It is the first time i use AsyncTask. How to get the value of stringBuilder back to main activity?